# How do I push all directories inside a parent directory into GIT

Tags: git, git-commit

Below is the directory structure of my directory named "Code".

```
Directory of C:\Name\Code
06/23/2016  12:15 PM    <DIR>          .
06/23/2016  12:15 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/23/2016  12:16 PM    <DIR>          Cpp
06/15/2016  06:49 PM    <DIR>          Java
06/22/2016  04:19 PM    <DIR>          Python
06/23/2016  12:17 PM    <DIR>          OtherStuffs
```

My Git account has Cpp and Java repository. I used to go individually to Cpp and Java directories and commit it to Git. So everything inside Cpp and Java gets committed to my Git repository Cpp and Java. Now I have added few more directories. I can sync those directories to Git by individually doing a "git init" on each of those directories.

Is there is an easier way to push all directories inside my parent directory "Code" into git without creating a repository named Code?

I do not want to create a parent directory "Code" in my Git repository. I just want to push all the sub directories to corresponding Sub directories in Git. Something like,

```
cd Code
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Pushing everything inside Code"
git remote add origin https://...   // Where should I make this point to ? I do not have "Code" repository in my Git
git push origin master
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: Please see my edit. I do not have "Code" repository in my Git. So where should I make the "remote add" point to ? I just want all the sub directories to get pushed into corresponding repositories in Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Code` repository is not initialized to git, nor is it linked with a repository. As a result it's not actually possible to just type `git push` from within your Code repository and expect it to push it's child directories.

The best thing I can suggest to you is setting up a bash (or zsh, depends on what you're using) alias that `cd`s into each directory and pushes separately.

`alias gpa='cd ~/path/to/Code/Java && git add . && git commit -m "autocommit" && git push -u origin master && cd ~/path/to/Code/Cpp && git add .` ... and end it with `&& cd ~/path/to/code`

However, the point of `git` is to be able to make atomic commits and know exactly what is being changed - so there really isn't a good reason to do what you're trying to do. I would continue to just use your process as normal - except you really *don't* need to have separate repositories for each of your different folders. Wouldn't it make more sense to simply have a `Code` repo?

Comment: But I already have repo named "Cpp", "Java" in my Git. What you are suggesting is, 1) Create a repo "Code" 2) Push everything into "Code" 3) Delete the existing repo named "Cpp" and "Java" right ?

Comment: yes sir! does that sound right to you? why do you need them separate? I only ask because it seems like you need to be pushing changes to them at the same time, so if they need to interact they should just be in the same repo.

Comment: I just didn't want all my directories to be under a single repo in Git. But I take your suggestion. Thanks.